# Lock Stored Procedure in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, locking

I have a stored procedure which inserts info into multiple tables and gets the IDs by `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. I would like to prevent multiple users from executing it at the same time, so that my IDs don't get mixed up.

How do I lock it? I have read about `sp_getapplock` and `sp_releaselock`, but there is no clear explanation how to use it. Below I put my procedure.

```
create procedure AddPerson(
    @Name nvarchar(255), 
    @LastName nvarchar(255), 
    @City nvarchar(255), 
    @Address nvarchar(255)
)
as
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
       insert into Location(Address, City)
       values(@Address, @City)

       declare @LocationID int
       set @LocationID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

       insert into PersonalInfo(Name, LastName)
       values (@Name, @LastName)

       declare @PersonInfoID int
       set @PersonInfoID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

       insert into Teacher
       values(@LocationID, @PersonInfoID)
    COMMIT
END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 1):

No *locking* of any kind needed - this behavior you're trying to accomplish is **already in place** implicitly.

`SCOPE_IDENTITY()` returns the new `ID` in the **scope** of each transaction - so if 10 users are running this simultaneously, each will get **their own, separate ID** back from  `SCOPE_IDENTITY`